# Run-path dependent library cannot locate its dependency during linking stage of a programme build on linux

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, libraries

I have written a [tutorial project](https://github.com/tarvanitidis/rpath_tutorial/tree/v0.9) whilst trying to understand the use of run-path dependent libraries on macOS and Linux. `simpleapp` depends on `libmymaths`, which in turn depends on `libfastmatrix`. `libmymaths` is a run-path dependent library and you can see the structure of the project [here](https://github.com/tarvanitidis/rpath_tutorial#structure). I am trying to use the OS specific macros (@executable_path for macOS and $ORIGIN for linux) in order to allow the binaries to be easily moved around without breaking, since their location is going to be resolved during run-time and substituted in the macros. However, although what I've programmed so far works nicely on macOS, it doesn't on Linux. Specifically, I'm getting the following error during the linking stage of simpleapp (you can reproduce simply with `./run.sh`):

`/usr/bin/ld: warning: libfastmatrix.so, needed by /home/thomas/Developer/rpath_tutorial/libmymaths/libmymaths.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)`

In [libmymaths' CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/tarvanitidis/rpath_tutorial/blob/master/libmymaths/CMakeLists.txt) I specify the rpath where its dependency (libfastmatrix) can be found, and that's verifiable with `ldd libmymaths.so` once libmymaths is built.

```
if(APPLE)
    set(TOKEN "@loader_path")
elseif(UNIX AND NOT APPLE)
    set(TOKEN "$ORIGIN")
endif()

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
    CXX_STANDARD 11
    CXX_EXTENSIONS FALSE

    BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH TRUE
    INSTALL_NAME_DIR "@rpath"  # Necessary prior CMP0042 introduction.
    INSTALL_RPATH "${TOKEN}/../libfastmatrix"
)
```

I have implemented the ld's suggestions as Fix 1 and Fix 2 in simpleapp's main [CMake script](https://github.com/tarvanitidis/rpath_tutorial/blob/v0.9/simpleapp/CMakeLists.txt), which allows the project to build.

```
# # Fix 1, -rpath-link (linux-specific ld option)
# LINK_FLAGS "-Wl,-rpath-link,${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../libfastmatrix/"

# # Fix 2, additional (unecessary for macOS) rpath, overwrites line 47
# INSTALL_RPATH "${TOKEN}/../libmymaths;${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../libfastmatrix"
```

However, this is against what I'm trying to achieve - make each library responsible for its own dependencies and not contaminate other projects with dependencies of dependencies.

1) What changes do I need to make to achieve my goal on Linux as I have done on macOS?
2) In case this is not feasible because the whole approach I am taking is incorrect, can you provide some proof or sources where this is documented?

I'm using:
CMake 3.5.1
ld 2.26.1
gcc 5.4.0

Thanks.

Comment: On Stack Overflow we want a code to be **in the question post itself**. You may have links to your project on github, but also provide part of your code, which describes your problem, in the question post (as text, use `Ctrl+K` or `{}` button for format it).

Answer (score 0):

I do this with my game project. Here are the steps I use to make it work.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

if (${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Linux")
  set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)
  set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "$ORIGIN/lib/:$$ORIGIN/lib/")
endif()

if (${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Linux")
    install(TARGETS SpeedBlocks DESTINATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build)
endif()
```

Note that I'm using a higher CMAKE version, so could be a bit different from what you need to do in 2.8.

After this I need to build the project, then run `make install`. The built binary will not have the RPATH set properly, but when I run `make install` (which basically just copies the binary and applies the RPATH from what I can tell) it gets set properly.

You can check if a binary has RPATH set properly by using

```
objdump -x path_to_binary_or_lib | grep RPATH
```

should output something like

```
RPATH                $ORIGIN/lib/:$$ORIGIN/lib/:/usr/local/lib
```

Comment: The main difference in our projects seems to be your double dollar sign origin in the rpath, `$$ORIGIN`. I have tried adding this but linking still failed.   

I'm using `BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH` to avoid `make install` (trying to keep the project minimally complete and to the point). Also, I updated my original posts with the versions of the software I use, thanks!

It's the dependency of simpleapp's dependency that cannot be found. That's cause each dependency resides in different location.